# How to use a python driver on a machine A to get data from this machine on a machine B by using a python script?

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a way so I can use a python driver on the machine A, who use windows XP and connected to a server who give instantly data, from a Machine B to get these data by using also python.

I was thinking about making the machine A as a server but i don't know what is the better way to do this?

Any ideas, tutorials, references ... ?

Thanks for your solutions to the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Use rpc (Remote procedure call) this is the easiest way.

http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html

take a look at the example in the Boolean section, it shows how to write a client and a server. It is actually quite easy, you write functions in the server that are called from the client as if they were running locally :D So your functions can return data and receive data seamlessly

Comment: thank you firebatdg for ur reply :) but what prog can i use for remote machine to hv the URI?

Comment: you need to specify your URI in your remote machine. Most of the time the server URI wont change, so you are free to hardcode that in your clients. It can be your ip address if you have a static ip for your server machine.